# changing exit node automatically?

Tags: exit-relays

I watch few geographically restricted channels via tor, by manually changing the exit nodes in the torrc file to the corresponding geographic location the go to the channel address.

Ideally, I would like to be able to do the following.
save or bookmark few channels, or make some desktop shortcuts, say for channels a,b, and c, so that when i click any it perform the following,
1- change the exitnodes value in torrc file to one corresponding to the given shortcut,
2- restart tor
3- go to the webpage that stream that channel.

values for a given shortcut (i.e., exitnodes, web address) are known.

is this doable?

please advise!

Comment: What platform are you on? Windows, Linux, OS X ?

Comment: I'm on windows 8

Answer (score 1):

When you start the Tor Browser, you can pass it a specific `torrc` file by using the `-f` option.

The fact that you can do this means you can create desktop icons that will open the Tor Browser with a `torrc` file of your choice, giving you the equivalent of `tor.exe -f torrc_USA`, `tor.exe -f torrc_UK`, etc.

For each country you want to use as an exit, create a separate `torrc` file, in each one including the `ExitNodes {country_code}` line.

Then create a shortcut icon to the Tor Browser Bundle, and edit it to include the appropriate `torrc` file. The shortcut is created automatically when you first extract Tor, so you just need to edit it. (You can do this by right-clicking on it, selecting Properties, and then adding `-f <location_of_torrc_file>` to the Targets box. Make sure these new arguments are outside of the `"` marks.)

Using this method you don't need to know the IP address of an exit node in a particular country - you just specify the country.

You can repeat the same method for each country you might want to use, resulting in several shortcuts which you can then rename appropriately. (e.g. "Start Tor Browser - US", "Start Tor Browser - UK", etc.)

Comment: if my shortcut target is "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe" and my torrc_uk file location is C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc_UK how will the edited target will exactly look please?

Comment: Hi @Richard. Ray commented on my answer something belonging to this.

Comment: Hi @Ray. Have you tried `"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe" -f C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc_UK`? (I don't have a Windows machine in front of me right now, but that looks like it should work.)

Comment: hi @Ritchard, yeah it always keep ignoring the file and use the original torrc. however i used the concept.. different torrc file for different exitnodes via a less economic method. I installed different instances of the  browser and renamed each in accordance with the exitnode geographic location. does the trick. there is even the chance to play multiple instances by changing the ports but I dont need that. so thx a lot for the idea :) much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The easiest path for you might be to set the [`AllowDotExit`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#AllowDotExit) flag in your torrc and use

```
http://myurl.com.myexitnode.exit/params
```

This should use the exit node you specified, in this case `myexitnode`.

Comment: Thx user. I'll try a search what you have suggested and see how i can do it :)

Comment: so do i just add, AllowDotExit to the torrc file like on a line on it self, then save. then when i type a URL in the Tor address bar i type lets say: http://bbc.co.uk.uk.exit/params? and sorry if i'm sounding an idiot but what params should be? whats "params" in general

Comment: @Ray: usually, the syntax is `AllowDotExit 1` on a line by itself.

Comment: Just take the url for whatever you want to do, (for example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GF60Iuh643I), and add .myexitnode.exit, like so: http://www.youtube.com.myexitnode.exit/watch?v=GF60Iuh643I. You need an exit node in that country, not just the country code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick detailed reply. how do i get an exit node in the country? when i do it manually I just set the value of "exitnodes" to {country code} for example exitnodes {no} for norway

Comment: is an exit node = an ip address that might be for instance allocated to me when i use...say exitnodes {no}

Comment: ok I have done a part of my homework, if in torrc file i add the following line: Exitnodes $551B D8CB 473F AED1 AF24 83F6 9DC6 71DD 2BE7 6000, $01C6 7E0C A8F9 7111 E652 C756 4CB3 2043 61FF FAB8
where what is after $ are fingerprints for exit nodes in norway and sweden. am I on the right path?

Comment: @Ray: how to get exitnodes in a country would be a good question on this site. (You might look into the downloaded directory files, but just go ahead and ask)

Comment: @Ray: The approach in this answer does not use `torrc` except for setting `AllowDotExit`. The rest is done in the browser location bar (where it currently says `http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8859/changing-exit-node-automatically`)

Comment: So we have to type a long URI for every web page instead of clicking on links?  That sucks even worse than having to relaunch TBB every time we want to change exit node configuration.

Answer (score 0):

i modify torrc file but keeps reverting to {us}

EntryNodes {uk} StrictNodes 1
ExitNodes {uk} StrictNodes 1